# How to check if String value is Boolean type in Java?

Tags: java, string, boolean

I did a little search on this but couldn't find anything useful.

The point being that if String value is either "true" or "false" the return value should be true. In every other value it should be false.

I tried these:

```
String value = "false";
System.out.println("test1: " + Boolean.parseBoolean(value));
System.out.println("test2: " + Boolean.valueOf(value));
System.out.println("test3: " + Boolean.getBoolean(value));
```

All functions returned false :(

Comment: Even if you set `value = "true"`?

Comment: Anyway, if you try one of the proposed approaches you should use String.equalsIgnoreCase(String s) to be on the safe side.

Comment: It appears that you are using these methods incorrectly. Please take a look at the Java docs for Boolean. http://www.j2ee.me/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html

Comment: @moxn - Based on the comment for a response, it appears that the OP wants to deal with strings that might need to be trimmed. However, it's certainly bizarre to complain that "false" is always parsed as false.

Comment: Khm, I'm aware what getBoolean,valueOf and parseBoolean functions do, Thank You! 
However the question is not about these functions. I wanted to know how lazily check if the string value is boolean. I quess I have to write some function that wraps "true".equals(value) || "false".equals(value).

Comment: Ragnar, the reason you're not finding it is that everyone has a different definition of what a boolean should be in string form. Is "TRUE" valid"? What about "True"? "TRUE" in double-byte characters? For perl hackers, having "1" not be true is offensive. :) So your method is going to have to be explicit about what it desires.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

- parseBoolean(String) returns true if the String is (case-insensitive) "true", otherwise false
- valueOf(String) ditto, returns the canonical Boolean Objects
- getBoolean(String) is a red herring; it fetches the System property of the given name and compares that to "true"

There exists no method to test whether a String encodes a Boolean; for all practical effects, any non-"true"-String is "false".

Comment: OK, this what I needed to know. I wonder why it is practical to have have any non-"true"-String as false? I mean in my mind valid inputs should be true and false and everything else is just not boolean input.

Comment: True, one could imagine a "BooleanFormatException" Exception, in analogy to the NumberFormatException that occurs when you try to parse a non-number String. I suppose it was deemed unnecessary at the time the library was written (1996!), for the targeted environments (embedded systems like set-top boxes and browsers).

Comment: Well there is no BooleanFormatException, but by using Apache Commons' BooleanUtils.toBooleanObject, if a string cannot be parsed, a null value will be returned, which can be quite useful.

Comment: "There exists no method to test whether a String encodes a Boolean; for all practical effects, any non-"true"-String is "false"."

this is obviously false!

Answer (score 48):

```
return "true".equals(value) || "false".equals(value);
```

Comment: Instead of hard-coding `"true"` and `"false"`, you can use `true.toString` and `false.toString`, just in case the string representations of "true" and "false" ever change ;)

Comment: In other languages, "1" and "0" are also considered valid for boolean string parsing, so I don't quite like the "hardcode true and false"-approach. OTOH the OP introduced the restriction to true and false, so well...

Comment: I was hoping to avoid this, since the input value could also be " true" or "True" or "TRUE" etc.

Comment: @Ragnar As I pointed out in a comment above, you should use String.equalsIgnoreCase(String s).

Comment: @moxn Thanks. I'll probably just wrap this into one funtion to check both true and false so I get bit cleaner code.

Answer (score 24):

Apache commons-lang3 has BooleanUtils with a method toBooleanObject:

```
BooleanUtils.toBooleanObject(String str)

// where: 

BooleanUtils.toBooleanObject(null)    = null
BooleanUtils.toBooleanObject("true")  = Boolean.TRUE
BooleanUtils.toBooleanObject("false") = Boolean.FALSE
BooleanUtils.toBooleanObject("on")    = Boolean.TRUE
BooleanUtils.toBooleanObject("ON")    = Boolean.TRUE
BooleanUtils.toBooleanObject("off")   = Boolean.FALSE
BooleanUtils.toBooleanObject("oFf")   = Boolean.FALSE
BooleanUtils.toBooleanObject("blue")  = null
```

Comment: There is also toBoolean, which returns false where this returns null. Seems a bit safer, but this lets you check for whether the object doesn't exist.

Answer (score 6):

```
if ("true".equals(value) || "false".equals(value)) {
  // do something
} else {
  // do something else
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Can also do it by regex:

```
Pattern queryLangPattern = Pattern.compile("true|false", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher matcher = queryLangPattern.matcher(booleanParam);
return matcher.matches();
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's a method you can use to check if a value is a boolean:

```
boolean isBoolean(String value) {
    return value != null && Arrays.stream(new String[]{"true", "false", "1", "0"})
            .anyMatch(b -> b.equalsIgnoreCase(value));
}
```

Examples of using it:

```
System.out.println(isBoolean(null)); //false
System.out.println(isBoolean("")); //false
System.out.println(isBoolean("true")); //true
System.out.println(isBoolean("fALsE")); //true
System.out.println(isBoolean("asdf")); //false
System.out.println(isBoolean("01truefalse")); //false
```

Comment: yes/no, y/n ...

Comment: This will work if you do the conversion from String by yourself. 
But the pure oracle methods Boolean.parseBoolean() and Boolean.valueOf() will return false for "0" and any other than "true" and "TRUE"

Answer (score 4):

The methods you're calling on the `Boolean` class don't check whether the string contains a valid boolean value, but they return the boolean value that represents the contents of the string: put "true" in string, they return `true`, put "false" in string, they return `false`.

You can surely use these methods, however, to check for valid boolean values, as I'd expect them to throw an exception if the string contains "hello" or something not boolean.

Wrap that in a Method `ContainsBoolString` and you're go.

**EDIT**
By the way, in C# there are methods like `bool Int32.TryParse(string x, out int i)` that perform the check whether the content can be parsed and then return the parsed result.

```
int i;
if (Int32.TryParse("Hello", out i))
  // Hello is an int and its value is in i
else
  // Hello is not an int
```

Benchmarks indicate they are way faster than the following:

```
int i;
try
{
   i = Int32.Parse("Hello");
   // Hello is an int and its value is in i
}
catch
{
   // Hello is not an int
}
```

Maybe there are similar methods in Java? It's been a while since I've used Java...

Comment: Quit teasing the Java dev with C# code.
That said, with Optional in Java 8, may be useful to write a little wrapper, where Optional.empty indicates non-bool.

Comment: If you read my answer carefully you will see that I'm not teasing him with C# code, but I'm suggesting he looks for methods in Java that do something similar to the methods in C#, as they conveniently both validate and convert. I've not used Java in a while, as I said, so I'm not sure whether features like that have been introduced.

Comment: It was a joke. "teasing."

Comment: Sorry, didn't get that ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Actually, checking for a Boolean *type* in a String (which is a type) is impossible. Basically you're asking how to do a 'string compare'.

Like others stated. You need to define when you want to return "true" or "false" (under what conditions). Do you want it to be case(in)sensitive? What if the value is null?

I think Boolean.valueOf() is your friend, javadoc says:

> Returns a Boolean with a value represented by the specified String. The Boolean returned represents the value true if the string argument is not null and is equal, ignoring case, to the string "true".
>
> Example: Boolean.valueOf("True") returns true.
> Example: Boolean.valueOf("yes") returns false.

Comment: Nice study. Only thing is, it does not work with Boolean.valueOf() too.

Comment: could you be a bit more specific what you're trying and what does not work?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but, didn't you parse "false"? If you parse "true", then they return true.

Maybe there's a misunderstanding: the methods don't test, if the String content represents a boolean value, they evaluate the String content to boolean.

Comment: I kind of figured it out too.

Answer (score 1):

Something you should also take into consideration is character casing...

Instead of:

```
return value.equals("false") || value.equals("true");
```

Do this:

```
return value.equalsIgnoreCase("false") || value.equalsIgnoreCase("true");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String value = "True";
boolean result = value.equalsIgnoreCase("true") ? true : false;
```

Answer (score 1):

Well for this, also have a look at org.apache.commons.lang.BooleanUtils#toBoolean(java.lang.String), along with many other useful functions.

Comment: This utility is not really helpful in this case since the following will return a boolean set to false: BooleanUtils.toBoolean("spaceship");

Answer (score 0):

```
return value.equals("false") || value.equals("true");
```

Comment: You could wrap the return statement into an try/catch construct, catch NPE and handle this exceptional state to return the real ... just kidding ;-)

Comment: @lutz - bad advice.  A `null` is almost certainly a bug and should result in an NPE.  Testing for `null` to avoid the NPE is almost certainly going to obscure the bug.  You should only test for `null` if it is explicitly stated that `null` has meaning.

Comment: unless you would expect a null value to be parsed. Then you could swap around the checks "false".equals(value) || "true".equals(value). Then again, you get casing issues.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you take a look at the Java docs for these methods. It appears that you are using them incorrectly. These methods will not tell you if the string is a valid boolean value, but instead they return a boolean, set to true or false, based on the string that you pass in, "true" or "false".

http://www.j2ee.me/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html

Answer (score 0):

See oracle docs

```
public static boolean parseBoolean(String s) {
        return ((s != null) && s.equalsIgnoreCase("true"));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  function isBooleanString(val) {
    if (val === "true" || val === "false"){
      return true
    } else {
      return false
    }
  }
isBooleanString("true") // true
isBooleanString("false") // true

isBooleanString("blabla") // false
```