# string as boolean

Tags: java, string, boolean, spreadsheet

I'm making a spreadsheet in Java.

I'd like to make a copy of the Microsoft Excel function `ISLOGICAL`. 
It checks whether a value is a logical value (TRUE or FALSE), and returns TRUE or FALSE.

All cells are arrays of string. This is what I have now:

```
public static String islogical(String[] value){
        String err = "#ERROR!";
        if (value.length != 1){
            return err;
        }

        boolean a = false;

        try{
            a = Boolean.parseBoolean(value[0]);
        }
        catch(IllegalArgumentException e){return err;}

        String ans = "FALSE";

        if(a){
            ans = "TRUE";
            return ans;
        }
        else{
            return ans;
        }

    }
```

I don't understand why, if my `string value = "8>3"`, that it doesn't give me back `true`. All inputs, except the string = `true`, gives back `false`.

Comment: `parseBoolean` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Java does not have a built in expression evaluation mechanism, it sounds like you'll need to write a Domain Specific Language.

Comment: Look here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762878/how-to-check-if-string-value-is-boolean-type-in-java

Answer (score 1):

> I don't understand why, if my 'string value = "8>3"', that it doesn't give me back 'true'

That happens because `parseBoolean()` does not evaluate expressions.

From the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#parseBoolean%28java.lang.String%29):

> Parses the string argument as a boolean. The boolean returned represents the value `true` if the string argument is not `null` and is equal, ignoring case, to the string `"true"`.
>
> Example: Boolean.parseBoolean("True") returns true.
>
> Example: Boolean.parseBoolean("yes") returns false.

Answer (score 1):

Boolean.parseBoolean() will return the boolean representation of a string.  So "True" returns true, every thign else returns false.

What you want is to evaluate the string - check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/evaluating-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;

public static String islogical(String[] value){
    String err = "#ERROR!";
    if (value.length != 1){
        return err;
    }

    boolean a = false;

    try{
        a = engine.eval(value[0]);
    }
    catch(IllegalArgumentException e){return err;}

    String ans = "FALSE";

    if(a){
        ans = "TRUE";
        return ans;
    }
    else{
        return ans;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `eval` method?  Here's an example from [Is there an eval() function in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605032/using-eval-in-java):

```
    ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("js");        
    Object result = engine.eval("3+4");
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameters for function evaluation must have simple data types, like numbers, booleans, strings, etc. All subexpressions must be calculated before you make a call for your function.

The expression “=ISLOGICAL(8>3)” must be evaluated in the following order:

1. Calculation of “8>3” subexpression. The result is a boolean value
   TRUE. The expression now looks like =ISLOGICAL(TRUE);
2. Function ISLOGICAL evaluation on the TRUE argument. The result is TRUE.

If your expression is =ISLOGICAL(“8>3”) then your function correctly returns FALSE, because the "8>3” has string data type, not boolean.
The best way for evaluation of excel-like expressions is the use of **reverse-polish notation**. Please follow [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) for details.